# A complete snippet for Wordpress child theme functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to use this code in my functions.php to create a child theme. I want to confirm that It will load the parent theme stylesheet, child theme stylesheet, and child theme js from `childtheme/js/scripts.js`. Is there anything else I have to consider in this snippet for a child theme's complete code? What about the footer?

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_parent_styles' );

function enqueue_parent_styles() {
   wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css' );
}

//load child theme custom CSS
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles', 11 );
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
}

//load child theme .js files. Note that the path is js/scripts.js
function wpb_adding_scripts() {
  wp_register_script('my_scripts', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/scripts.js', array('jquery'),'1.1', true);
  wp_enqueue_script('my_scripts');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpb_adding_scripts' );

?>
```

Comment: Your code seems fine. It will load the parent theme stylesheet, child theme stylesheet, and child theme js from `your-childtheme/js/scripts.js`. Js will be loaded in the footer.

Comment: @AkhtarujjamanShuvo Thanks! I have previously used a child theme I found on the internet, and the theme was jumping when the page loads. I was unsure about the issue, and it was because of an incorrect snippet! I wanted to put this code between your hands' guys for review and to refine it so that the whole community can benefit from this work. I appreciate the time you have given in reviewing the code!